# Apache doesnt appear to be using multiple cores

Tags: apache-2.2, http, multi-core

I have a dedicated server with 16gb RAM with a Xeon E5504(8cores @2.0GHZ) running with Centos 7. I ran the top command and can see that 7 of the cores are close to idle most of the time and then one single cores is going flat out. Ive see it go above 100% which i dont understand.

```
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16479600 total,  1233968 free,   616824 used, 14628808 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   523260 total,   499720 free,    23540 used. 15342640 avail Mem
```

The server is used only as a web host. Apache, MySQL and PHP. I havnt made any changes to apache from its default config. I have heard that the default apache config supports multiple threads, but this clearly isnt the case.

mysqld and httpd are the only things using large amounts of resources. In total apache gets around 100k requests per week. More than enough for this server, but as i continue to add more sites, i dont want to slow it down since everything is on the same CPU.

I read into it an it seems that "prefork" needs to be modified in order to make apache take more resources. I ran the following command to see the default config and it doesnt look like prefork is even installed

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c
```

Im not sure how to test the system to know what the current config is and why only one core is being used. I didnt notice much of a performance increase when moving sites from a low end single core VPS to this server, so im worried something is wrong with the config.

I checked /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf and all thats here are the virtual hosts. There are no lines related to the max clients and other values ive seen people using in the prefork if statement.

Comment: How many `httpd` children do you see running ? Show the `MaxClients` setting.

Comment: there is no MaxClients value in the conf file. I cant see any of the MPM fields in the conf file, so it doesnt look like its setup. Whatever the settings are would be the default apache settings. The httpd children are popping up randomly. ive seen 4 of them at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top tells your your system isn't doing anything, as it is 100% idle.

The fields have the following meaning and don't specify specific cores.

```
       us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
       sy, system  : time running kernel processes
       ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
       wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
       hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
       si : time spent servicing software interrupts
       st : time stolen from this vm by the hypervisor
```

Comment: is there a way to see that status of each CPU so i can confirm that multiple cores are active?

Comment: `htop` has a nice visual display of individual cores. However, forget about that. You misinterpreted the output of `top`, but that is no reason to mistrust the OS scheduler to do it's work after you learned the real meaning of what you saw. 100K requests per week means one request every 6 seconds on average, this will not even register as any load at all in most cases.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. So am i safe just leaving apache configured the way it is? out of the box it should be able to make full use of the CPU and RAM? So far SQL has been the only thing i had to boost max connections with as it was giving the too many connections error quite often. i have it at 1000 now.

Comment: Yes, for such a low traffic site, Apache defaults are usually OK. If you get much more traffic, you might have to start tweaking, but before that you need to learn more about this. MySQL running out of connections on such a site might indicate a problem with your website code though, but that's a different issue.

Comment: i have several wordpress sites running. could be a dodgy plugin, but thats a different story. for now ill keep it as is. our of curiosity. how many requests per day etc should the server be getting before i have to consider tweaking this stuff?

Comment: That's impossible to say as it depends on your site. You have to watch the numbers (load, IO wait, load times of your site) and if they get problematic, you need to start thinking about this. WP plugins are a prime candidate for problems - lots of badly written ones out there that have a high impact on the performance.